# compile error on method to check if service is running

Tags: android, service, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I found some code that tells you if your service is running.  But it is getting compile errors and I don't know why.  My service class name is AudioService (the class that extends Service) and I am getting compile error on the if statement line of code where it says,

`AudioService.equals(service.service.getClassName())` and the error message from the compiler is,

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method equals(object) from type object

I am using the method inside of the Activity that is bound to the service.  I call `bindService()` in the `onResume` method and `unbindService()` in the onPause.  Just want to use some method to make a Toast message to show that the service is actually running.

What am I doing wrong and how to get this code working?

```
private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (AudioService.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: please paste your stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `AudioService.class.getName()`

```
 private boolean isServiceRunning() {
  ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (AudioService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.application.MyService"
                .equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```